# What is the etymology of Laches? (The Ancient Greek name.)

Tags: greek, etymology

I'm studying Plato, but am ungreeked. Does the Ancient Greek name [Laches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laches_(general)) have a known or suspected etymology? My searches have only turned up the modern legal term, related to the Latin word laxo. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to come from the root λαχ- *lakh-* of the verb [λαγχάνω *lankhanō*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dlagxa%2Fnw) "obtain by lot, possess by lot".

It's hard to say more precisely what the name would have meant, or why this meaning was thought suitable for a man's name. This is not infrequently the case with Greek names. In this case, Λάχης *Lakhēs* looks like it might originally have been a hypocoristic "clipping" of some longer compound name beginning Λαχ- *Lakh-*, such as the rare but attested Λαχέμοιρος *Lakhemoiros*, which means something like "he who is allotted his portion/share/lot/fate".

(*Lachesis*, the name of one of the three Fates, is also from this root, which makes sense because the Fates allot destinies to mortals.)